# Automorphism proof ( simple)

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

So the problem is given by

Let G be a group and define $\pi $ : $\rm\:G \to G\:$  by $\pi(a)$ = $a^{-1}$, for every a in
G. Prove that $\pi $ is an automorphism of G if and only if G is abelian.

Though i have no idea how to prove it clearly $\pi$ is  Bijection on G
i would like to use the fact that the identity element in G is $a_{e}$ and that the Kernel of G is $a_{e}$

So knowing $\pi (a_{e})$ = $(a_{e})^{-1}$ = $a_{e}$ and if the kernel is preserved i believe i can conclude i have a bijection somehow?

i believe i have one direction of the proof as well

Assume $\pi$ is an automorphism Want To Show G is abelian

$\pi(ab)$ = $(ab)^{-1}$ = $(b)^{-1}(a)^{-1}$

$\pi(a)$ $\pi(b)$ = $(a)^{-1}(b)^{-1}$

but by homomorphism property of $\pi$

$\pi(a)$ $\pi(b)$ = $\pi(ab)$

thus

$(a)^{-1}(b)^{-1}$= $(b)^{-1}(a)^{-1}$

So G must be abelian if $\pi$ is an automorphism

Now for the other direction i believe my confusion lies in  im not certain i can assume $\pi$ is a homomorphism if i can i think i could show that $\pi$ is an automorphism.

If someone could help me implement an idea to prove i have a bijection and point me in the right direction on the second half it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Taking inverses is a bijection because it has an inverse map (in particular, itself). If you assume it is a homomorphism, then $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ implies $ba=ab$, for every $a,b$ (how?). If $G$ is abelian, then $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ (the first equality is true generically in all groups - check).

Comment: put in post under edit cause i couldn't make it look right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is Abelian group, for any $n\in\Bbb Z$, the mapping $g\mapsto g^n$ is a homomorphism (since $(gh)^n=g^nh^n$). In particular, it is a homomorphism for $n=-1$, and the inverse function of the inverse operation is itself, so it is clearly a bijection.

(Additionally, written additively, we have that $x\mapsto nx$ is a homomorphism for all $n$.)

Comment: If G is Abelian group, for any n∈Z, the mapping g↦gn is a homomorphism (since ($gh)^{n}=g^{n}h^{n}$)

Sorry i dont really understand why  ($gh)^{n}=g^{n}h^{n}$ is a homomorphism

Comment: The mapping $g\mapsto g^n$ is the homomorphism. It preserves unit and multiplication.